# How much bigger is the "Large" system text setting compared to the "Normal" setting in Android?

Tags: android

Android's accessibility settings allow for the user to change the system font sizing. To take advantage of these settings developers are instructed to use 'sp' units for text sizes. This is all clear.

But what I need to know is how much larger (or smaller) the text scales when the system default setting is changed? Where might I find the scaling percentages for each of the possible settings?

Answer (score 1):

Stock android OS's outline the following size scales at the system level:

```
Small   - 0.85
Default - 1.0
Large   - 1.15
Largest - 1.30
```

However, this varies when looking at manufacturer flavors of Android. TouchWiz, for example, specifies the following options:

```
Tiny    - 0.8
        - 0.9
Default - 1.0
        - 1.1
        - 1.3
        - 1.5
Huge    - 1.7
```

Comment: Where did you find these numbers for TouchWiz and the stock Android OS?